# Oracle VirtualBox on Linux host with Windows guest running terribly slow

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox

I recently got myself a new, more powerful workstation. With Linux Mint (now in version 19.1) as my main system and some programs (that my business depends on) only running on Windows, I also installed the (to my knowledge) newest version of Oracle VirtualBox, hosting Windows 7 as a guest. The problem is: The guest system is now running terribly slow and feels extremely laggy.

What's surprising me is the fact that I also had VirtualBox with almost the same setup installed on my old machine and it was working fast and flawlessly. The new machine is much more powerful, so I'm wondering, what's going on. Here's my setup:

**Old machine**

- Linux Mint version 18.x, ext4 file system
- VirtualBox in version 5.x with Guest Additions installed
- dynamic memory allocation (about 50GB), sometimes running into problems with the pagefile
- 6-core AMD CPU, 3 of which I had assigned to the guest system
- 16GB of RAM, 8 of which I had assigned to the guest system
- NVidia GeForce GTX 980 with 4GB of VRAM

**New Machine**

- Linux Mint version 19.1, ext4 file system
- VirtualBox in version 6.0 with Guest Additions installed (installing 5.x makes no difference)
- static memory allocation (about 128GB)
- HP Z820 with 16-core Intel Xeon CPU, 8 of which I have assigned to the guest system
- 64GB of RAM, 32 of which I have assigned to the guest system
- NVidia GeForce GTX 980 with 4GB of VRAM

On both machines, "VT-x/AMD-V", "Nested Paging" and "IO-APIC" was/is activated. The system installed (Windows 7) is exactly the same, the software as well. So, to me it looks as if VirtualBox should be running a bit faster on the new machine; and yet, it feels extremely laggy... to the point that I really can't do any work.

Any ideas, what could be causing this? Is there anything that I could try?